# Azure Functions concurrency and scaling behaviour

Tags: concurrency, azure-functions, serverless, azure-http-trigger

There's a bunch of Azure Functions concurrency questions here on SO but none of them addresses this specifically.

I'm wrapping my head around the scaling scenario for a HTTP-triggered Function app (runtime is Node.js if that matters). I'm coming from the AWS Lambda world where each concurrent invocation [results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) in a new Lambda instance:

> If the function is invoked again while a request is still being processed, another instance is allocated, which increases the function's concurrency.

What confuses me about the Azure Function app is this piece from their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#understanding-scaling-behaviors):

> A single function app only scales out to a maximum of 200 instances. A single instance may process more than one message or request at a time though, so there isn't a set limit on number of concurrent executions.

**Under which circumstances will a single FA instance process more than one request at a time?**

Answer (score 0):

This line probably refers to below [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#configure-host-behaviors-to-better-handle-concurrency):

> The host.json file in the function app allows for configuration of
> host runtime and trigger behaviors. In addition to batching behaviors,
> you can manage concurrency for a number of triggers. Often adjusting
> the values in these options can help each instance scale appropriately
> for the demands of the invoked functions.
>
> Settings in the host.json file apply across all functions within the
> app, within a single instance of the function. For example, if you had
> a function app with two HTTP functions and [maxConcurrentRequests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-output#hostjson-settings)
> requests set to 25, a request to either HTTP trigger would count
> towards the shared 25 concurrent requests. When that function app is
> scaled to 10 instances, the two functions effectively allow 250
> concurrent requests (10 instances * 25 concurrent requests per
> instance).
>
> Other host configuration options are found in the [host.json configuration article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json).

Comment: See this link for more information on maxConcurrentRequests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#configure-host-behaviors-to-better-handle-concurrency